# How to use Backbone with Jade correctly

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, pug, passport.js

Hi I´m developing a expressjs backbonejs with mongoose, my template engine is HTML (with text.js).

My app have a navbar with Register and Login links and a container where I put contents. I implemented a login system with passportjs, it works well, when you are logged in you´ll have a req.user object with your user info.

Now I´m blocked cause I´d like to hide the navbar links if I´m logged in.

When I did the POST to /login if all is success, i redirect to /account and load another view with it template, I´ll have the req.user data but the navbar view doesn´t have it and then I can´t hide the links.

I tried to pass to jade cause I can put the HTML code of the navbar in a template and after POST /login render a jade template that contains the navbar template with "extends". But in this cause I lost all my Backbone functionality cause I can´t navigate with # in the URL.

Wich is the correct way to do this?

Hope you understand me, regards.

Answer (score 0):

You may solve the situation by using singleton pattern. I.e. a global config object which has a method *isLogged* for example. The idea is to initialize this object in the entry point of your application. The place where you have the needed data and later access it via that singleton. For example:

```
var AppConfig = (function() {

    var isLoggedFlag = false;
    var changeLoggedStatus = function(value) {
        isLoggedFlag = value;
    }
    var isLogged = function() {
        return isLoggedFlag;
    }

    return {
        isLogged: isLogged,
        changeLoggedStatus: changeLoggedStatus
    }

})();
```

When you know that the user is logged just use:

```
AppConfig.changeLoggedStatus(true);
```

In your view just check

```
if(!AppConfig.isLogged()) {
    // hide whatever you need to
}
```